# Cross domain worker url, how to make it work?

Tags: javascript, url, cross-domain, web-worker

I have been trying to make cross domain worker url work, this might be a duplicate question but I couldn't make any solution to work, here is what I am doing:

```js
  const url = new URL('./worker/a.worker.js', import.meta.url);
  const workerBlob = new Blob([
      'importScripts(' + JSON.stringify(url) + ')',
    ], { type: 'application/javascript' });
  const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(workerBlob);
  this.WasmVisionWorker = new Worker(blobUrl);
```

This is throwing error - *

> Cannot use import statement outside a module at ....

- 

Basically, in my worker I am importing different scripts using ES6 'import'
i.e.

```
import scan from '../scan.js';
```

I read here - [ES modules in service workers](https://web.dev/es-modules-in-sw/)

to use import statements, we have to provide - type: 'module' while creating new worker:

```
this.WasmVisionWorker = new Worker(blobUrl, {type: 'module');
```

With this, getting error - cannot use 'importScripts()' with modules, should be related to this:

```
const workerBlob = new Blob(['importScripts(' + JSON.stringify(url) + ')',
    ], { type: 'application/javascript' });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your worker script really is stored in an other domain, then what your "loader" script should look like to load a module script is

```js
import "${ url }";
```

So with everything:

```
const url = new URL('./worker/a.worker.js', import.meta.url);
const workerBlob = new Blob([`import "${ url }"`], { type: 'text/javascript' });
const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(workerBlob);
this.WasmVisionWorker = new Worker(blobUrl, { type: 'module' });
```

This will load your script as a module script.

However note that your script must be sent with the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers for this to work (the same would be true in non Worker environment).

Comment: ImportScripts() issue has been resolved, thank you but worker is still not loading, I checked network calls and page I don't see the worker instance. So, just to give you more info, worker script is also importing some other script, basically a dispatcher which will communicate with other classes/scripts being imported by same dispatcher class/script and also to communicate back to main thread using worker instance.

Comment: Add a `this.WasmVisionWorker.onerror = console.error` to see if something goes wrong during the execution. Then if you can, introduce logs in the module chain to see which one succeed and which ones fail. (Also, is the chain resolved properly from the main thread?)

Comment: So, do I need to create blob URL for each dependency as well? As I am importing more modules inside the worker and those modules are importing other module in their respective scripts. All are using relative paths only and I am getting error that path is not being resolved. Hence, my question do I need to create blob urls for each or is there any other way? Thanks!

Comment: how to resolve dependencies?

Comment: @aman I'm sorry I don't really understand your issue. Using the code in the answer you should be able to load dependencies from the loaded module just normally. https://cross-domain-worker-import-a.glitch.me/ [source project A](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/cross-domain-worker-import-a), [source project B](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/cross-domain-worker-import-b). Both are cross-origin and load the *entrance.js* module from the other origin, which will itself load the *inner.js"  module using a relative path. That all works for me.